# Identifying material on masonry wall

Tags: concrete, masonry, hanging, mortar, load

The inner side of an exterior wall in my house has, behind the plasterboard, a kind of masonry which I'd like to identify.
I attach pictures.
It looks like concrete but it's quite easy to drill: I can very easily drill it with a 2mm wood/metal drill bit in a HAND (i.e., not electric) drill.
This material is at least 5cm thick (maybe more), as inferred from the hole I drilled.

This is a UK house built in the '70s (probably second half).
The material is definitely **not** plasterboard (aka drywall).

So, what's the name of that substance? Is it safe to hang heavy stuff (e.g., a radiator) to it using rawlplugs?

Thanks!

https://i.postimg.cc/1yjwG8Nh/1.jpg

https://i.postimg.cc/fzxdQ5qD/2.jpg

Comment: where are you located and how old is this house?

Comment: From these relatively poor photos, it looks like concrete to me,

Comment: @d.george: edited the post to clarify, thanks

Comment: It looks like there is some sort of bracket fastened to the wall. What was that used for? Is it sturdy and can it be removed? If so that should give you a clue as to how to hang stuff on this wall. If it's an exterior wall it has to be sturdy enough to hang stuff on. Just need to figure out how.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose: no, that thing is screwed to the plasterboard (drywall) layer above the masonry one.

Comment: What is behind this surface? A wood framed wall? More masonry? Is it hollow?

Comment: @Jack: not sure. I only know that the outermost layer is roughcast.

Answer (score 1):

Reads like plaster/gypsum cement, if it drills that easily.

Pictures offer no insight.

Weight-bearing loading is likely to be dubious.